# Unable to pause S3 file upload

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am following code sample mentioned [here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/S3TransferManager.html) for S3 file upload using S3TransferManager. From samples it appears that to be able to pause an ongoing upload `FileUpload` reference is required.
What I am unable to understand is how do I get reference of `FileUpload` if it has to be paused from a different request/thread. Also, `transferManager.uploadFile` appears to be synchronous operation, is this correct? Please advise.

Comment: `transferManager.uploadFile` is an asynchronous function call.  What specifically are you attempting to do that's not shown on that page?

Comment: @AnonCoward issue I am facing is that the moment ```upload.pause()``` is called ```java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: null``` is thrown and ``Transfer failed.``` is printed in log. So, if I catch exception - I am able to persist upload information using ```resumableFileUpload.serializeToFile(path)``` but resume is not happening when this line executes ```FileUpload resumedUpload = transferManager.resumeUploadFile(persistedResumableFileUpload)```

Comment: @AnonCoward  also I am referring following sample but it appears to have no pause+resume functionality


https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/b320aeae1a3e650bffc23f9584a26a7ca177cbb2/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/aws/example/s3/XferMgrUpload.java